# Display Image from server not working on image tag for tiff file. Angular

Tags: angular, image, web, upload

I am trying to load an image from the server. I was getting unsafe error earlier but after using domSanitizer it was resolved. However, no any image is loaded in the component. I am not able to figure out, where the code execution went wrong.

```html
<button id="btnPreview " class="ml-2 btn-md actions " aria-hidden="true " 
(click)="previewImage() ">
</button>
<ng-template #imagePreview>
   <img [src]="imageToShow" alt="Place image title" *ngIf="!isImageLoading">
</ng-template>
```

Service.ts

```js
    readonly GetTiffPreview = (
    placeHolderText: string,
    placeHolderTextFont: string,
    placeHolderPosition: string
    ): Observable<any> => {
    let param = new HttpParams()
    param = param
    .set('placeHolderText', String(placeHolderText))
    .set('placeHolderTextFont', placeHolderTextFont)
    .set('placeHolderPosition', placeHolderPosition)
    return this.http.get(
    this.configService.getApiUrl() + '/slipsheet/getslipsheetforpreviewtext',
    {
    responseType: 'blob',
    params: param
    }
```

Component.ts

```js
    previewImage(){
    const delRef = this.dialog.open(this.imagePreview, {
    closeOnNavigation: true,
    autoFocus: false,
    width: '350px'
    })
    this.isImageLoading = true
    const body: SlipsheetTemplateModel = this.slipsheetTemplateForm.value
    const placeHolderPosition = StampLocation[body.placeHolderPosition]
    delRef
    .afterOpened()
    .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
    this.ssService.GetTiffPreview(
    body.placeHolderText,
    body.placeHolderTextFont,
    placeHolderPosition
    )
    ),
    debounceTime(100),
    takeUntil(this.toDestroy$))
    .subscribe(
    (data) => {
     this.createImageFromBlob(data)
     this.isImageLoading = false
     },
     (error) => {
    this.isImageLoading = false
    console.log(error)
    })
    }

    createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener(
    'load',
    () => {
    this.imageToShow = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
    String(reader.result)
    )
    },
    false
    )

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image)
    }
    }
```

the encoded base64 string is of format data:image/jpg;base64,SUkqAKwEAAD///+ACACA////gAgAgP///4AIAID///+ACACA////gAgAgP///4AIAID///+ACACA.
I guess there is some issue with the conversion if anyone could help me on this

Comment: Do you have onPush?

Comment: No, I have not used any onPush

Comment: Do you see any error in the console ? Are you able to add a debug point inside the `createImageFromBlob()` method ?

Comment: yes, the debug point gets hit and no any error in the console